# Make an activity full-screen

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-theme

I got an activity which i want to be full-screen. I tried to change the theme. But it doesn`t work. Then i tried it programmatically but i doesn´t work neither. Any idea what i did wrong?

```
public class FullActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full);

    ImageView imageViewFull;

    imageViewFull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewFull);

    imageViewFull.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

  }


}
```

[Here u can see a screenshot, titlebar still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVmWm.png)

And how i said "NoTitlebar THeme" didn´t work for me.

Comment: where did you set the NoActionBar theme?

Comment: in the xml
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to values, then `styles.xml` and change the first row like this:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

And then go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and at aplication's theme add:

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: thank u very much that worked for me in my styles.xml was:
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: one more question i got more classes than one. And now the actionbar on every class is missing. Anyway to change it so that 1 class has the actionbar and the other not?

Comment: You can create a custom ActionBar method to implement in any class you want: see this [link](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)